# Transforming matches from findall/finditer to variables or strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, findall

I have a large file that basically looks like a diary and want to extract all information concerning each date to further process it.

```
File looks like this:

Mittwoch, 13. September 2017
19:00 Uhr
20:00 Uhr
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

Mittwoch, 20. September 2017
18:00 Uhr
19:30 Uhr
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

To realize this I parsed the dates  with following code which returns each date as one match (I used findall and finditer, because I am unsure which is better to handle).

I now want to assign each match as a variable with a number to form start- and endpoints.

This way I hope to split the document into its single events.

The problem is, that I have no Idea how to assign matches as strings or variables and can not find anything helpful.

Code:

```
    # finditer
    matches = re.finditer((Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])", contents) # finds all Dates and shows them in a List (Day , Number . Month ( ) Year)

    for match in matches:
        print "{g}".format(g=match.group()) # returns dates below eachother without ''

    # findall
    matches = re.findall("(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])", contents) # finds all Dates and shows them in a List (Day , Number . Month ( ) Year)

    for aTuple in matches:
        print "\n",('%r%r%r%r%r%r%r' % aTuple) # print findings after new line below eachother with ''

    for Weekday, Comma, Day, Dot, Month, Space, Year in matches:
        print "\n", Weekday, Comma, Day, Dot, Month, Space, Year
```

So in the end I would like to have something like:

Date1 = ("Mittwoch, 13. September 2017")

Date2 = ("Mittwoch, 20. September 2017")

This would allow to extract everything between Date1 and Date2.

Thank you for your help and effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work on your file line-by-line.

Create a function that detects whether a single line contains a date. After you find your first date with that function, start collecting the following lines as your content.

When you hit the next line containing a date, process your current list of content lines, and start over. Continue until you hit the end of the file.

If your dates are formatted consistently you may want to rely on a date library (such as Python's datetime with German localization) for the parsing instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is, that it is not the only file and this shall become the template for extracting the necessary information. It will differ if the start- and endpoints are a date or not. So I need a way to make variables from the matches to be abled to search and extract between those variables. Isn't there a simple way to make each matchobject a variable in order of occurrence?